# Confusion regarding simple linear regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to understand simple linear regression. Our instructor shared a co lab note book and also a data set related to salary.

Link of co lab note book

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15r8dpI9h10ie1QOP7h2C7WjlgHNrfY8i#scrollTo=Ze9vpBTf-Bol

Link of data set

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10DiyyZMGVoAKxkqw_kvEX3W7VqXKbKr2T-8w6raFhSQ/edit?usp=sharing

Actually i am confused about the last code cell especially the spots highlighted in yellow in attached snap . There is X_train but i think it should be X_test since in above code line we passed X_test to `plt.scatter`. Please correct me if i am wrong?
[image]

Comment: Yes, it should be `X_test` in `plt.plot` as well to visualize the performance on the test set.